# Unusual integral notation

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

When I was learning analysis, I often wondered why I couldn't seem to find anything like $$\iint f(x) (dx)^2$$ in a standard calculus text, and concluded that it should be meaningless – even though, since we can differentiate functions multiple times, it would make sense that we can also *integrate* them repeatedly.

But then I stumbled upon [this blog entry](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/05/dropping-in-on-gottfried-leibniz/) by the creator of *Mathematica*, showing that Leibniz had similar notation in mind when he was developing the calculus, and found out about the differintegral operator, using which the above expression looks like $D^{-2}[f(x)]$.

My question is, why don't we see this notation that often in basic analysis courses? What is the graphical meaning of such an expression – i.e. how would its behavior affect the shape of $f(x)$? And how would one solve it? Is there even a definite analog of it, and if so what is its geometrical meaning?

Comment: Studying physics, i frequently encounter expressions of the form $\mathrm{d}^3x$, and treat them as if they express $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$

Comment: There's a lot of different notations, some of which are favoured by other fields. For example, for a single integral, physicists apparently prefer $\int\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)$. I've also seen $\int \mathop{\mathrm{d}z} \int \mathop{\mathrm{d}y} \int f(x,y,z) \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$ In the end, as long as you know what you're talking about and it's unambiguous, it should be okay.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about notation of "higher order anti-derivatives". For example, we have second derivative $d^2f/dx^2$, the OP wants to denote the second anti-derivative by $\iint f(x) (dx)^2$.

Comment: ^ That, and some hints on the graphical intuition behind it. I am aware of the existence of multiple integrals in multiple dimensions

Comment: I remember reading once in some book the notation $$\int\cdots\int f\, \mathrm d x^n$$ Don't really remember where, but it seemed pretty natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @Mathaholic said, if you write out the operations involved in integrating a function twice, you get:

$$\int \left(\int f(x) dx\right) dx$$

It looks like this has been compressed via the following process:

$$ \int \left(\int f(x) dx\right) dx \to \int \int f(x) dx dx \to \int \int f(x) (dx)^2$$

It's a little confusing, since it suggests to me we are integrating a single function over the Cartesian product $x\times x$. But $f$only has one argument.

Basically, its mixing geometric and operator notation, much like $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is defined more inline with operator theory. I've seen this quite a bit in time series analysis, where we use the Backshift $(B)$ operator as a variable:

$$(1-B)Z_t = Z_t - BZ_t = Z_t-Z_{t-1}$$

A key theoretical issue in time series is finding "unit roots", where you solve expressions like:

$$(B^2+2B+1) = 0 $$

To find if the time series:

$$(B^2+2B+1)Z_t$$

Is stationary.

This is a bit of a diversion, but I was reminded by this example of how operator notation can be very confusing if you're not used to to.

Comment: Interesting. The same logic you explained for the $B$ operator also seems to be common practice for quantum mechanical operators such as $\hat p = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.